# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Flife1' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

My stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GET_MBR_DWN_DTL] (@MBR_ID VARCHAR(50), @LEG_POS CHAR)    
AS BEGIN    

WITH CTE(MBR_ID, MBR_LEG_POS, MBR_NM, MBR_JOIN_TT, LVL, MBR_UPR_ID, MBR_SPR_ID) AS            
(            
        SELECT
            CAST(MBR_ID AS VARCHAR(100)) as MBR_ID,
            MBR_LEG_POS, MBR_NM, MBR_JOIN_TT,
            CAST(MBR_UPR_ID AS VARCHAR(100)) as MBR_UPR_ID,
            CAST(MBR_SPR_ID AS VARCHAR(100)) as MBR_SPR_ID,
            LVL=0
        FROM MBR_MST
        WHERE MBR_UPR_ID=@MBR_ID and MBR_LEG_POS=@LEG_POS     

        UNION ALL            

        SELECT
           CAST(M.MBR_ID AS VARCHAR(100)) as MBR_ID,
           M.MBR_LEG_POS,M.MBR_NM,M.MBR_JOIN_TT,
           CAST(M.MBR_UPR_ID AS VARCHAR(100)) as MBR_UPR_ID,
           CAST(M.MBR_SPR_ID AS VARCHAR(100)) as MBR_SPR_ID,
           LVL+1
        FROM MBR_MST M
            JOIN CTE F ON CAST(M.MBR_UPR_ID AS VARCHAR(100))=CAST(F.MBR_ID AS VARCHAR(100))       
)    
SELECT * FROM CTE ORDER BY LVL, MBR_JOIN_TT OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)    
END
```

but when I run

```
USP_GET_MBR_DWN_DTL 'Flife1', 'A'
```

it shows error

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure USP_GET_MBR_DWN_DTL, Line 5
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Flife1' to data type int.

Comment: Please Help .. this causing lot of problem for me..

Comment: What are the types of MBR_UPR_ID and MBR_LEG_POS ?

Answer (score 2):

It's very strange. What data to you have in `MBR_UPR_ID`? if it's varchar than you shouldn't get an error, if it's an `int` - why do you trying to compare it with `varchar` Flife1?

My advices:

- Format your code! Why do you hate spaces so much? it's impossible to read queries written as blobs. Remember, other developers may require to read and change your code and they'll curse you if you would write code like that;
- Take a look at your data types in your tables. I would say that if you have to convert before join it's high probability that you doing something wrong;

**update** Ah! found it. you've just mixed fields in your CTE declaration:

```
WITH CTE(MBR_ID,MBR_LEG_POS,MBR_NM,MBR_JOIN_TT,LVL,MBR_UPR_ID,MBR_SPR_ID) AS
```

should be

```
WITH CTE(MBR_ID,MBR_LEG_POS,MBR_NM,MBR_JOIN_TT,MBR_UPR_ID,MBR_SPR_ID,LVL) AS
```

But you could write just `with CTE` - you have all column names inside your CTE. I also suggest to remove all cast you have in your a query, it should work allright without it

Comment: MBR_UPR_ID is  varchar(50)

Comment: check my updated answer. you've just mixed columns in cte declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following fix:

```
--code before the union
FROM MBR_MST 
WHERE CAST(MBR_UPR_ID AS VARCHAR(100)) =@MBR_ID AND MBR_LEG_POS=@LEG_POS           
UNION ALL
--rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a handy query for highlighting the differences between the two tables in your UNION:

```
SELECT 
    c1.ordinal_position, 
    c1.table_name, 
    c1.data_type, 
    c1.column_name, 
    c2.column_name,
    c2.data_type,
    c2.table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ordinal_position, column_name, table_name,data_type
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'TABLE_ONE') c2 on c1.ordinal_position = c2.ordinal_position
where c1.TABLE_NAME = N'TABLE_TWO'
and (c1.column_name <> c2.column_name
    or c1.data_type <> c2.data_type)
order by c1.ordinal_position asc;
```